# Distance between two pixels but belonging to different sets

Tags: matlab, distance, set, pixel

How can I find the `distance` between two pixels belonging to two different sets? I think `pdist` does that but for a single object?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "distance" and "sets"?

Answer (score 0):

Just compute the euclidian distance:

```
p1 % a 1x2 vector of the x y position of the first pixel
p2 % a 1x2 vector of the x y position of the second pixel
d = sqrt( ( p1(1)-p2(1) ).^2 + (p1(2)-p2(2)).^2 );
```